# How do I find the sum of every X rows in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, submatrix

I have a 189 x 4914 matrix and am trying to find the sum of each row in each 1x26 sub-matrix. How would I go about this?

Many thanks.

Comment: So the result would be 189x189?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = 26;
result = reshape(sum(reshape(x.', n, []), 1), [], size(x, 1)).';
```

You can look at intermediate results to see how this works: `reshape(x.', n, [])`, then `sum(reshape(x.', n, []), 1)` etc